# Spring 3.0 and Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-3

I'm trying to configure Spring 3.0 with Maven. I've read http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

In my pom.xml I've defined the following repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then I tried with the most basic dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

where

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5-RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
```

However, if he spring-core is not found.

[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:org.springframework.core:jar:3.0.5-RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-recipes: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.obliquid:spring-recipes:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework:org.springframework.core:jar:3.0.5-RELEASE in com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release) -> [Help 1]

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the EBR copies, but I have a project that works fine with the "From Maven Central" ones detailed on that page.

Comment: Yes I had a limited success with Maven Central, however not all Javadocs, sources were available. Sometimes I had problem with components, but probably because I don't know the correct names. I wanted to see if directly from springsource the situation was better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
<org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
```

instead of

```
<org.springframework.version>3.0.5-RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
```

Comment: It wasn't your fault they went against the grain when they named their artifacts different from conventional Maven artifact naming. I think what you tried should be the name.